# Unable to connect to Robot Simulator

Tags: android-studio, emulation, pepper

I have installed Android Studio and the Pepper SDK, and I'm able to boot up the tablet emulator and instal applications and run them using the Pepper API. When I start the emulator, the Starting Emulator screen stays at 34%, and the Robot Viewer does not show up.

I've tried connecting to the robot viewer, but I get an error about changing my IP address. I've tried 127.0.0.2, 10.0.0.5, and even connected to the tablet shell and found the eth0 address; however, I'm still unable to connect the tablet emulator to the robot viewer. Also, the tablet emulator does not connect to WiFi.

Comment: The info about the IP address is not clear. Do you have screenshots? Can you tell us what the IP addresses you are mentioning are pointing to? How can you know the tablet emulator does not to connect to WiFi, if it does not boot up in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Check [this section of troubleshooting of the official documentation](https://qisdk.softbankrobotics.com/sdk/doc/pepper-sdk/ch1_gettingstarted/installation.html?highlight=troubleshooting#troubleshooting). This emulator does not work on every platform.

If it does not work on your platform, you can use a normal Android emulator, running an Android API 23. I usually use the 4" WVGA (Nexus S) device to get a similar screen size and resolution. The main difference is that you will not be able to [get the focus](https://qisdk.softbankrobotics.com/sdk/doc/pepper-sdk/ch2_principles/focus_lifecycle.html).